# Angularjs unit testing directive with controlleras

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck with how can I unittest my custom directive with controllerAs.Here's the code -

```
var SomeDirective = function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        model: '='           
    },
    template:  (__dirname + '/Some.html', 'utf8'),
    link: link,
    controller: "SomeController",
    controllerAs: 'some',
    bindToController: true,
};
  function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    if (_.isUndefined(scope.some.model)) {
        throw new Error('The directive requires a "model" ');
    }
}
```

Controller -

```
var  SomeController = (function () {
var SomeController = function SomeController (
    someService
   ) {

  };
SomeController.prototype.dosomething = function ( ) {
           //do something
}    

SomeController.prototype.dosomething2 = function ( ) {       
       //do something2
};
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Since using `ControllerAs` does not change the actual behavior of objects, wouldn't it suffice to just test the object as is?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese m not really sure how do I inject controller and test the link function. I can create the child scope using $rootScope.$new()  and but how would I test the error message "'The directive requires a "model" ' since the scope.model now refers to scope.some.model?